# ConstraintException does not raise in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, exception

I want to write a test that handles `FOREIGN KEY constraint` error when deleting a record, but ConstraintException is not raised.

the table's schema like below

```
class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :sequence
    end
  end
end

class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :states do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :sequence
      t.references :country, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

I confirmed to raise ConstraintException on delete it in `rails console`.

```
c = Country.create!(name: 'country')
State.create!(name: 'state', country: c)
c.destroy
```

> (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
>      (6.1ms)  rollback transaction
>   ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = ?
>   from /Users/masamoto/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'

However, no error occurred in the rspec, and it seemed to me that it was deleted normally.

```
describe 'Error' do
  it 'Destroy' do
    country = Country.create!(name: 'hohooho')
    State.create!(name: 'oooooo', country: country)
    country.destroy
  end
end
```

> Error
>         Destroy
>
> Finished in 0.0339 seconds (files took 3.27 seconds to load)
>   1 example, 0 failures

I thought that the transaction was not committed, I tried setting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`, but it did not change.

And I tried explicit commit, but the result is the same.

```
describe 'Error' do
  it 'Destroy' do
    country = nil
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      country = Country.create!(name: 'hohooho')
      State.create!(name: 'oooooo', country: country)
    end

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      country.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

That is because your foreign key constraints are not in the test database.

Add following to application.rb file

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

and run

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

should fix the problem

more information can be found here [missing foreign key in test database](http://davidvg.com/2010/04/06/missing-foreign-key-constraints-in-rails-test-database)